# Async await with Task.FromResult(0)

Tags: c#, async-await

Not sure if I am messed up with my understanding of how async await works, but here is the problem I am stucked at.
Consider a contrived example

1. This code blocks UI

   ```
   public async void LoginButtonClicked()
   {
    //create a continuation point so every following statement will get executed as ContinueWith
    await Task.FromResult(0);
    //this call takes time to execute
    Remote.Login("user","password");
   }
   ```
2. But this does not (obviously)

   ```
    public void LoginButtonClicked()
    {
    Task.Run(()=>{ Remote.Login("user","password");});
     }
   ```

I like to use method 1 because I don't want to spin long work using a Task.Run rather I prefer framework handle this form me. But the problem is The call to Method 1 seems blocking.

Comment: `await` only does anything fancy if the thing to it's right has not completed. a `Task.FromResult` always returns a completed task, and so the method continues merrily on its way past that `await` point.

Comment: And this old Eric Lippert [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx) might help: "The whole point of async methods it that you stay on the current thread as much as possible."

Comment: `Task.FromResult` should not be called with `await`: [Should I await on Task.FromResult Method Calls?](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/should-i-await-on-task-fromresult-method-calls)

Answer (score 5):

Using await/async only stops you from blocking the UI if all the long-running operations you call are async. In your example your `Remote.Login` is a synchronous call, so regardless of what the prior `await` line does, this will block your UI.

You need to either get an async version of your actual long-running operation (eg something returning a `Task`) or if that is not possible, then you can resort to `Task.Run` in order to move this work to the `ThreadPool`.

What you want if possible:

```
public async void LoginButtonClicked()
{
    await Remote.LoginAsync("user","password");
    // do anything else required
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Every async method has its context.

When the Task starts it might run in a new `SynchronizationContext`. "Might" because if the task is already completed, like `Task.FromResult(0)`, then no other `SynchronizationContext` is created and the original one is used.

Awaiting for a task means that when the task is finished, the next statement will run in the original SynchronizationContext.

This behavior can be changed using the `Task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)`. This means that the next statement will continue on the same context. But this will change nothing by doing `Task.FromResult(0).ConfigureAwait(false)` because the task is already completed and the original context will be used.

Therefore your `Remote.Login("user","password");` will be run in the original context, thus blocking the UI thread which runs on the same context.

If you would have something like:

```
public async void LoginButtonClicked()
{
  await Task.Delay(5000).ConfigureAwait(false);
  Remote.Login("user","password");
}
```

Then `Remote.Login("user","password");` would execute in the thread pool context thus being on a different context than the original UI context.

So the best way to fix your code is to create a `Remote.LoginAsync()` as stated in @Nicholas W answer.

**NOTE on performance:** if you have an async method with multiple await statements, and you don't need some of those awaits to do work on UI or web app thread, then you can use `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)` in order to prevent multiple switches to the UI/web-app context which slices its execution time.

Answer (score -2):

1. You run in parallel Task.FromResult(0); and still wait for Remote.Login("user","password"); to be finished
2. You run Remote.Login("user","password"); asynchronously.

You have to create async version of Remote.Login

```
    async Task LoginAsync(string user, string password)
    {
        Remote.Login(user, password);
        await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

and call it

```
    public async void LoginButtonClicked()
    {
        await LoginAsync("user", "password");
    }
```

Comment: That's a synchronous method, not an asynchronous method.